# Meaning of ということで this time?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm always bothered by ということで. What does it mean this time? Could it be a kind of "by" ("Are you going to kill me by accident too?")

> なぁに、姉さん。その銃は。 ……私も暴発ということで殺すの？

By the way, since 暴発 is used as a noun, shouldn't it be **だ**ということで?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「なぁに、姉{ねえ}さん。その銃{じゅう}は。 ……私{わたし}も暴発{ぼうはつ}**ということで**殺{ころ}すの？」

In this sentence, 「～～ということで」 means "**by calling it ~~**", "**by claiming it as ~~**", etc.

In meaning, it is highly synonymous to 「～～ということにして」.

> "What's that gun for, Big Sister?  Are you gonna kill me by calling it an accidental discharge?"

Finally,

> By the way, since 暴発 is used as a noun, shouldn't it be だということで?

It can be, but that would be too "formal" or wordy for the situation.　Frankly, it would be too bookish a line to utter when your life is on the line.

The speaker could have chosen to say 「暴発ってことで」 as well if she had wanted to sound even more informal.

Comment: actually, .... if you wrote it as 私も暴発**だ**ということで殺すの？wouldn't it just look grammatically weird? with だ there, wouldn't it translate to something like "I'm also called an accidental discharge, and kill me?"

Comment: No, it would not be weird at all.  What is weird is your translation because that translation, while being gibberish, could even apply to the original phrase without the だ.　It is just nonsense taking the 私も暴発 part to mean "I am also 暴発".

Comment: my confusion stems from the fact that だ by itself is a sentence ending particle. So だということ and ということ, or だということで and ということで, are identical in meaning and usage except for the excessive "literary" sense of the だ form?

Comment: `the fact that だ by itself is a sentence ending particle` 関係ないけど 「だ」は sentence ending particle (終助詞) じゃなくて auxiliary (助動詞)じゃなかったっけ。。。

Comment: `"I'm also called an accidental discharge...` ←　いや、「私も」は「暴発(だ)」の主語じゃなくて、「殺すの？」の目的語ですね。。　「私を/も（暴発ということで）殺すの？」→「暴発(だ)ということにして、私を/も殺すの？」って言い換えてみたら・・・