# Understanding ということで設定した?

Tags: grammar

> 夕弦。耶倶矢を「動」とするなら「静」のキャラ**ということで**設定した君だったが、いつの間にか耶倶矢よりもナチュラル中二な上に、肉食なキャラになっていた。

This text appears in あとがき. The writer is commenting on one of the characters he invented as if he was talking to her. 耶倶矢 is designed to be “active” while 夕弦 is designed to be “silent”.

So how should I understand the bold ということで? Does the で mean “because”? Or it means “として”?

Answer (score 2):

Practically you can replace this particular ということで with として.

I cannot really explain the construction grammatically, but you can take this to be similar to (independent) participle construction in English (sorry I don't know the proper name for the construction; I mean something like *Leaving the town*, he headed for the north) as follows:

First,

- Xということだ = It is that X.

で makes it adverbial:

- it being that X

So it is like embedding X as the description of the situation.  If this 'theory' is correct, 君を「静」のキャラということで設定した translates literally as *I set you, it being that you are the static character*, or *I designed you, your being the static character*, which is *I designed you as the static character* in more normal English.

As you may be aware, there are a couple of related questions:

- [ゲストハウスの当番だということで、郷田さんと熊沢さんがゲストハウスまで案内してくれることになった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54875/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7-in-this-sentence)
- [なぁに、姉さん。その銃は。 ……私も暴発ということで殺すの？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/60111/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7-this-time)
- [当面はノーサンキューということで。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47731/meaning-of-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7)

where:

- ゲストハウスの当番だということで : Being in charge of the guest house
- 私を暴発ということで殺す : kill me, it being that it was an accidental discharge
- 当面はノーサンキューということで（理解してください） : (Please understand) it being that I don't want it for now.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can all case of ということで be understood this way? For example, can this example be understood the same way?https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/83111/what-is-the-function-of-the-で-of-ってことでということで

Comment: Although I'm not absolutely certain, perhaps mostly,  The 'theory' is general - but maybe too general to be really useful, and you have to guess to fill the gap. Regarding the linked question, yes. 文句ないわね is the main clause thus: _You don't have objections about it being that the 'things after' will depend on the result, do you?_